# Eloquent 'with()' returns null

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have a simple relationship between two models: User and Prescription. A user has many prescriptions. In the PrescriptionsController, when I try to get the user that the prescriptions belongs to, it returns null when using with().

PrescriptionsController

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $prescriptions = Prescription::with('user')->where('prescription_for', $user_id)->get();
    return response()->json($prescriptions);
}
```

The result from that Eloquent query:

```
[{"id":1,"prescription_for":1,"prescription_by":1,"prescription_content":"Paracetamol 120mg - O cutie. Mod administrare: 1 Dimineata | 0 Pranz | 0 Seara","created_at":"2020-10-13T17:33:35.000000Z","updated_at":null,"user":null}]
```

You can see that the last parameter is null.
In my User model, I have set up the relationship using:

```
public function prescriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prescription::class);
}
```

And the Prescription model:

```
protected $table = 'prescriptions';
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $timestamps = true;

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I am using VueJs so I cannot just do $prescription->user->name as you can in Blade files, that's why I need to eager load the data.

The way I set up the Prescriptions table:

```
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('prescription_for');
$table->foreign('prescription_for')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('prescription_by');
$table->foreign('prescription_by')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->string('prescription_content');
$table->timestamps();
```

Any ideas to why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Try this `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'prescription_for');`

Comment: Double check that you're authenticated, also. Otherwise Auth::id() will not have a value.

Comment: This worked: return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'prescription_for');  You can answer it and I will mark it as correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `prescriptions` table, your primary key is `prescription_for`. If the parent model does not use `id` as its primary key, or you wish to find the associated model using a different column, you may pass a third argument to the `belongsTo()` method specifying the parent table's custom key :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'prescription_for');
}
```